# tsql to know when sql service was installed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Tsql, how can I find out when MS SQL server was installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM login is created when you install SQL Server, so:

```
SELECT createdate 
    FROM sys.syslogins 
    WHERE name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

This will return an incorrect result however if you've ever restored the Master database.

Comment: Isn't this only if "local system" is chosen as the service account? The concept is good though: just need to work out the best login to use.

Comment: @gbn: I'm not sure about that. I was under the (perhaps incorrect) impression that this login was always created. I've checked a couple of systems where I'm using a domain account for the service and this query still seems valid on those systems.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first 100 `principal_id` values are reserved in [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+). Based on what I see in one of my sys.server_principals (SQL Server 2005, SP3), I'd try this:

```
SELECT MIN(create_date) FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id > 100
```